# practice vs practise sentence question

Tags: british-english, orthography

Do both these sentences work? (British form)

she needs more English practice.

she needs more English practise.

Answer (score 2):

In British English. Practise with an S is a verb, with a C a noun.  The same is true for License/Licence.  Advise/Advice is the same again - but sounds different, so it's a good way to remember which is which, if you find it difficult!

Comment: So for example "She needs more English practice" and "He needs to practise English more"

Comment: I was about to downvote for an answer given to an easily-flagged duplicate, but like the sound advice. But using the variously defined term 'British English' gives the impression that everyone living in Britain adopts the same practice, and that not to do so would be wrong. I've seen no rule saying that people in Britain must adopt a certain practice, or that people in say the US must practice differently. Though I admittedly don't usually mix styles.